# How to make 3-phase 230V AC zero crossing detection with Arduino UNO

Tags: pwm, solid-state-relay, zero-crossing

I am working on making a 3-phase power control of a heating element using PWM control with an SSR. I have a problem making a zero crossing detection to control the duty cycle of the PWM to turn it on and off.

Can anyone explain in detail how to make a zero crossing detector for a 3-phase system and what is the accuracy

Comment: What zero-crossing signal/voltage/current are you trying to detect (the clue's in the question)?

Comment: If using PWM, why does it need to be zero-crossing?  A heater is purely resistive, so zero-crossing isn't needed.  Do you perhaps mean "firing angle?"

Comment: You don't seem to have understood the answers to your previous questions on this topic. You can't use PWM (in the usual sense) with SSRs. You use time / duty-cycle control with zero-cross SSRs or use firing-angle control with non-zero-cross SSRs. Once triggered the SSRs will stay on for the remainder of the cycle.

Comment: I apologize, I am unable to differentiate  PWM and phase angle control as some expert told me:
The firing angle can be controlled using a pulse-width modulation (PWM) signal that is generated by the Arduino. The duty cycle of the PWM signal determines the firing angle of the SSR, with a longer duty cycle resulting in a later firing angle and less power being delivered to the load.

Comment: you may be overthinking this ... what are you heating up?

Answer (score 1):

Atmel Application Note AVR182 shows how to make a zero-crossing detector.

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/Atmel-2508-Zero-Cross-Detector_ApplicationNote_AVR182.pdf

The AppNote tells us something very useful:
"the maximum current through the AVR’s clamping diode should not be higher than 1mA"
which is not information that's in the Atmel328P datasheet.

Of course, this isn't a true "zero crossing" detector but the voltage will be changing so quickly it will be very close.

(As I'm sure you're aware, playing with mains can be painful.)